# Reutilização de threads

Tags: c++, thread, multithreading

Estou a fazer um addon para nodejs. Uma das funções é responsável por fazer parametrizações o audio que chega, dos vários clientes. Eu quero que essa parametrização seja feita numa thread.

```
void buffering(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {

Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
HandleScope scope(isolate);

int size = args[1]->NumberValue();
int final_read = args[2]->NumberValue();
int inicio_read = args[3]->NumberValue();
int client_id = args[4]->NumberValue();

Local<Object> bufferObj = args[0]->ToObject();

buf = node::Buffer::Data(bufferObj);
char mini_buf[80000];//char mini_buf[4096];
memcpy(mini_buf, buf, size);
//Função para a correr numa nova thread
int teste_buf = Julius[client_id].Audio_Buffering(mini_buf, size, final_read, inicio_read, client_id);
```

Se o `Audio_Buffering` fosse executado uma só vez eu poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
std::thread t[num__threads];
t[client_id] = std::thread(&SREngineJulius::Audio_Buffering, &Julius[client_id], mini_buf, size, final_read,inicio_read,client_id);
```

O problema é que esta função, para o mesmo cliente, vai ser executada várias vezes (até que o stream do cliente acabe). Uma solução seria iterar e criar novas threads, mas a longo prazo isso criaria muito lixo. Alguma maneira de reutilizar uma thread? Ou de criar e destruir logo de seguida?

Comment: Tem como você explicar o que deseja em sentido mais amplo? Digo, independente de se o thread vai ser usado para processar áudio, ou texto, etc... O que você quer? Existe uma tarefa a ser executada de tempos em tempos? Como o programa sabe quando o thread deve parar?     Por que criar vários threads geraria lixo (se podes destruí-los)? etc